# Element mat-checkbox-ripple is cut off

Tags: angular, angular-material

There is a list with checkboxes (MatCheckbox) and when user clicks on checkbox the animation is cut off.

[image]

Every wrapper of checkbox has

```
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
```

styles. I see that mat-ripple-element has absolute position and cannot understand why it's cut off. I created a small demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-unhnym?file=src/app/app.component.css). I'd appreciate any help/clarification how it can be fixed without adding any padding or removing **overflow: hidden;** property.

Comment: if you remove overflow hidden from wrapper element it will not cut off ripple effect

Comment: @Chellappanவ It's just an example. In my project I have several parent elements with overflow: hidden; property and it cannot be easy to remove.

Comment: If that is the case you can add some padding to checkbox element or wrapper element. it will resolve the issue

Comment: @Chellappanவ Extra padding cannot be added because of UX-requirements. The question was more about why absolute element is cut off if it isn't in the document flow.

Comment: When we set overflow hidden on parent element, any overflow to child element will not be visible.Since ripple effects happening outside of mat-checkbox it was hidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed changing position from absolute to fixed:

```
::ng-deep mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-inner-container .mat-checkbox-ripple {
  position: fixed;
  left: inherit;
  top: inherit;
  transform: translate(-12px, -12px);  // -<checkbox width>/2, -<checkbox height>/2
}
```

Updated example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wdhgat?file=src/app/app.component.css).

Comment: This doesn't work when the page can scroll.

Comment: @blackhard have you found a solution for mat-slide-toggle-ripple? The container uses 'transform' to toggle between on and off, which makes position:fixed to stay within the boundaries of the container.

Comment: This solution helped me. My problem was that the parent `div` had no padding and the ripple could not overflow it and it got hidden behind it. Thank you.