# mat-slide-toggle-ripple gets cut off by parent element with overflow: hidden

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

In my application i have multiple mat-slide-toggles that are aligned to the left margin. The parent wrapper needs to be set to overflow:hidden in order to work with scrollbars for child elements. The problem that i'm facing is making the mat-ripple show in its entirety, because it is clipped off by the wrapper.
I have a stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2muwt7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

I tried @blackhard 's solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67300657/element-mat-checkbox-ripple-is-cut-off)  but mat-toggle works a little different than a regular checkbox in that it uses 'transform' to toggle on and off, and that makes 'position:fixed' be within the boundaries of the toggle container.